# Subscribe on route.queryParams and route.params at the same time

Tags: angular

I have next URL with both `route.params` and `route.queryParams`

```
.../search/VALUE1?method=VALUE2
```

I have created route

```
{
  path : 'search/:id',
  component: MyComponent
}
```

Component

```
export class MyComponent {
...
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
  combineLatest(this.route.queryParams, this.route.params)
    .subscribe([queryParams, params] => {
       console.log(ID:' + params('id') + ',M:' +queryParams('method'));
       // code
    })
}
```

But there is a problem - when user changes main param and query param at the same time - then subscribtion will be called twice, e.g.
user calls

```
.../search/VALUE1?method=VALUE2
.../search/VALUE3?method=VALUE4
```

Console log

```
ID:VALUE1,M:VALUE2
ID:VALUE3,M:VALUE2   <-- redundant method call
ID:VALUE3,M:VALUE4
```

How to subscribe on both `route.params`, `route.queryParams` but call subscribtion only once?

**What tried**

```
     private method: string;
//
     ngOnInit() {
       this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
          queryParams => {
             this.method = queryParams['method'];
       });

       this.route.params.subscribe(
          params => {
             console.log(ID:' + params('id') + ',M:' + this.method);
             // code

          }
     }
```

And this works perfectly.
But can I be sure that `this.method` will contain correct value at the subscribtion?

Comment: Tried getting them separately?

Comment: You can try experimenting with other rxjs operators, like [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html)

Comment: @Arcteezy I have added code what I tried. And this works. But can I be sure that `this.method` will contain correct value at the subscribtion?

Answer (score 0):

For getting params, you dont need subscription. The one below works fine when changing both.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe( p => {

      console.log("ID :" + this.route.snapshot.params['id'] + ',M:' + p['method'],)

    })
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when queryParam is not changed, e.g. 

`.../search/VALUE1?method=VALUE2

.../search/VALUE3?method=VALUE2` log will not be called after second http call

Comment: Worked for me. Can you provide a live demo?